# Multiple cart experience

Tags: e-commerce, shopping-cart

So I'm working on an e-commerce website and it has different marketplaces (3 basically), now I want to make separate cart for each of them as through research we figured out that people hardly purchase combined items from all three marketplaces and majority of orders come from either of them three.
I'm attaching a very rough screenshot of what I'm thinking to do.
One disadvantage of the approach I have taken is that it is compromising the visibility of other products in other carts to improve that, I have tried giving an overview of other carts below all products in current cart.

Please let me know if I can do it in anyway better.

Thanks[image]

Comment: What happens if I press continue on the Flipkart tab? Does it also checkout all the other carts?

Comment: No it will checkout just the Flipkart cart

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. If you use the interface Ameen showed below, users can just checklist the items they wanted to checkout, whether it be from one store or three at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Would advise against hiding the contents of each shop behind tabs. Instead, you could group them while keeping them visible. Sure the list might be a bit longer but users can see it all by simply scrolling instead of clicking the tabs. Refer to the example below.

[image]